# OWC Webparts not supported in 2010? Alternative?

Tags: web-part

We have OWC web parts in 2007 Sharepoint that allows us to host cube related and excel sheets in a web part. If we upgrade to SharePoint 2010 will it not be supported? What are the alternatives. Please advise

Comment: Excel spreadsheets are directly supported in 2010: no add-on needed. I am not sure what "cube related" means, so just left this as a comment. Word documents are supported in 2010 as well.

Answer (score 1):

Alternate is use the Excel Calculation services, for this you need enterprise edition.
SSRS and Excel Services Reports also can help.